# How to Configure Tomcat with Crystal Reports 2008 Server V1 SP3 after it's already been installed?

Tags: tomcat, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, business-objects, maximo

### Background

I inherited a bunch of systems that were implemented using less-than-best practices and now I'm trying to get them to play nicely together.

### Components

- SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI Server / Crystal Reports 2008 Server (as far as I can tell, these are the same thing with different names due to company takeovers)
- IBM Maximo 7 with an integration tool for BOE XI / CR 2008 Server

### Goal

- I'd like to integrate BOE XI / Crystal Reports with Maximo, which there are components available to do.

### Problem

- The IBM toolkit requires configuring Crystal Reports 2008 for Tomcat server, which it presumes was installed alongside CR2008/BOE XI.
- The Tomcat portion of the web server was not installed.
- CR2008 / BOE XI is very...finnicky...software in my opinion, and I'm not sure if it will work after the fact.
- We only have one server. The live, production server. (working on changing this, but I'm new here and it is what it is for now.)

### Question(s)

- Does the CR 2008 installer allow you to configure Tomcat -- and *only* Tomcat -- as a component of the installer? I don't want to mess anything additional up
- Is there a manual way to get the files to configure tomcat without the installer? I've configured tomcat before so that would put me ahead of the game.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of integration you have, but as I know Maximo 6.28 and Maximo 7.1.1.11 both require bocrystal.war to be compiled on the Maximo Admin machine and added to webapps folder of TomCat. I am curious how you are able to run Crystal Reports from Maximo without this.

Is it possible to get a disk image of the production server and put it on VMWare? You could then experiment with your TomCat install. I am surprised you don't get a development server to play with. Windows Azure gives you a free 90 day trial, so if you don't have local resources, you can use Azure...